# How to init, refresh fragment when notification comes?

Tags: android

Is it possible to handle events like when notification appears the action like auto refreshing, initmethod in Fragment. I have workmanager implemented I could do it using sharepreferences, but it is not instant and user has to refresh it by himself.
I made a little research and there is kotlin channels, do they works instantly, automatically iwthout user action?

EDIT:

Notification Service

```
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {

        // sending broadcast
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = "notification_appear"
        intent.putExtra("notification_appear", true)
    
[...]
}
```

MyFragment where I would like to receive this

onViewCreated

```
        createReceiver()
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext())
            .registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter("notification_appear"))
        refreshWhenChangeToolbarPosition()
```

just method in teh same fragment

```
    private fun createReceiver() = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val isNotificationAppears = intent?.getBooleanExtra("notification_appear", false) ?: return

            Log.d("notification_appear", "$isNotificationAppears")
            if(isNotificationAppears) {
                initToolbar()
            }
            when(intent?.action) {
                        "notification_appear" -> initToolbar()
            }

        }

    }
```

Unfortunately I haven't receive any logs from onReceive method...
why?

EDIT2:
It works I also should send using LocaoBroadcastManager

```
        // sending broadcast
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = "notification_appear"
        intent.putExtra("notification_appear", true)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Comment: You can do using LiveData or local broadcast. You can fire event in your service and observe changes in your fragment

Comment: local broadcast deprecated, https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager

Comment: then you can go with live data or sharedflow

Comment: Could you please look at my edit post? it doesnt work :P :)

Answer (score 1):

Using LiveData

LiveData is an observable data holder class. Unlike a regular observable, LiveData is lifecycle-aware, meaning it respects the lifecycle of other app components, such as activities, **fragments**, or services. This awareness ensures LiveData only updates app component observers that are in an active lifecycle state.

Comment: is it not deprecated, should I use stateflow??

Comment: Of course you can use it too.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options, the common way is to send broadcast like this :

```
val intent = Intent("YOUR_ACTION")
intent.putExtra("key","value")
sendBroadcast(intent)
```

from your MessagingService (such as FirebaseMessagingService), then register broadcast in your fragment (preferably in `onViewCreated()` ), don't remember to unregister your broadcast.

the other option is using `LiveData` or other observer pattern libraries like `RxJava`.
in this case you have to define your observable object in your service class then observe it from your fragment.

Note that if using RxJava you have to take care of disposing the observeable. LiveData is a lifecycle aware component so you don't need to worry about the memory leak or emitting while fragment is not available.

Comment: so basically send broadcast from onMessageReceived method in notification. override fun onMessageReceived() {} and then receive the broadcast in fragment on viewcreated? and it isntantly refresh if notification comes?

Comment: Yes exactly, your fragment will be notified as long as the broadcast is alive, unregister your broadcast in your `onDestroyView()` method.

Comment: Could you please look at my edit post? it doesnt work :P :)